# Basis for the space of linear maps.

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, I've always thought about the notion of basis as something related to *vector spaces*, i.e., given a (real) vector space $V$, a basis is a (minimal) set of *linear independent* vectors $\mathcal{B} = \{\textbf{v}_1, \dots , \textbf{v}_n\}$ such that $V = Span(\mathcal{B})$. I was trying to understand what does exactly mean when people write the term *basis* when talking about linear maps. Let's say we fix two vector spaces $V$, $W$ with bases $\mathcal{B}_V$ and $\mathcal{B}_W$. Now if we consider the collection of linear maps $\mathcal{L} = \{L:V \rightarrow W \}$, how a basis for $\mathcal{L}$ can be formally defined?

Comment: The linear maps between two vector spaces form a vector space themselves. A basis of that vector space is defined exactly the same way as any other basis: a maximal set of linearly independent vectors, where the vectors are linear maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of basis is the same: a linearly independent set which also spans. An example of a basis, *induced by* the bases on $V,W$, is the collection $\{T_{ij}: 1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m\}$ where $T_{ij}:V\to W$ is the [unique linear map](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3263766/568204) such that for all $k\in\{1,\dots, n\}$,
\begin{align}
T_{ij}(v_k)&=
\begin{cases}
w_j&\text{if $k=i$}\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
It is a standard, but useful and very informative exercise for you to prove that this collection of maps actually forms a basis for the space $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ for all linear maps from $V$ into $W$.